# Storing JSON object in JSON column in MySql2 using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, json, mysql2

I have a JSON object that looks like this -

```
{
"questions": 
            [{
               "question_id": "1",
                "question": "Choose games you're currently playing",
                "answers":
                   [{ "answer_id" : "1", "answer": "game1", "checked": false },
                    { "answer_id": "2", "answer": "game2", "checked" : true }]
             },
             { 
               //...
             }]
}
```

I'm trying to store it in a JSON column using MySql2.

My query -

```
const query = `INSERT INTO user_questions(_id, questions,created_at, updated_at, deleted) 
                VALUES(1, '${JSON.stringify(questions)}', NOW(), NOW(), 0)`;
const result = await db.query(query)
```

But I'm getting the following exception error -

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

**Edit**: I found out it's because of the apostrophe in the question. If I try to run the query without it, it works fine.

Comment: have tried to log the query and try to execute from IDE and see if that works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldnt use direct inserts use instead this approach

```
const query = 'INSERT INTO user_questions(_id, questions,created_at, updated_at, deleted) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
const result = await db.query(query, [1, JSON.stringify(questions), NOW(), NOW(), 0)]);
```

which escapes all columns properly: [using-prepared-statements](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#using-prepared-statements)